# Show 0.00 when there are no values. Currently it shows 1000

Tags: sql, decode, oracle12c

I have a column called 'contract_quantity'. For some weird reason it's showing 1000 values in the DB table, while in the GUI I can see that the value is N/A, i.e there is no value but the table shows it as 1000, instead of 0.00.

Is there any way around it using the DECODE function or anything else? I basically want the following logic for the column 'contract_quantity':

When there is no value, show 0.00 (and not 1000)
When there is value, show that value

Any suggestions?

Comment: "the table shows it as 1000" what does that mean? Does the row actually contain 1000 or is it what you see in some client app?

Comment: Add your `select` statement so we can help you, even a simplified version of the original one if it does have sensitive data.

Comment: SELECT contractual_quantity
FROM quantities

Comment: The table shows 1000, when there are no values. The value shown in the GUI is N/A. However, the table shows it as 1000.

Comment: What you claim, sounds quite impossible to me. Please, post a test case: CREATE TABLE and INSERT INTO statements, as well as SELECT which proves what you're talking about.

Comment: It sounds more likely that your table does actually store 1000, but your GUI (whatever that is - your own application, or a standard client?) is treating that as a 'magic number' somehow and replacing it with the N/A string instead. (Less likely, perhaps, is that when you query the table - again, in which client? - you've done something like `set null 1000`, though that would be an odd thing to have set up, and forgotten about...)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your GUI has trouble dealing with NULL values. Have you tried the [COALESCE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) function? In your case, the follwoing query should do the trick:

```
SELECT COALESCE(contractual_quantity, 0.00) FROM quantities;
```